# Why is my database receiving null values? Posting to an API using Python3

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I have seen a couple of answers to this question, but none of the solutions offered are that similar to my particular setup.
I am posting values to a database using an Api called DbGate.
The format I send from a browser looks like this:

```
https://www.myurl.com/api/mssql/dbo/uspAddLaneTimings?laneSequence=2&rfidUniqueId=020047D0C653&planningLaneSeq=1&sensorId=202481599234152
```

When I run this by typing the URL into Chrome on my PC, or using Chromium on my Raspberry Pi, it works fine.
Data is correctly posted to my table, and the browser responds with the ID of the added record:

```
{"value":[{"ID":18}]}
```

I am trying to send the POST request from a RaspBerry Pi using  Python3. This is my first ever Python project.

The SQL looks like this:

```
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @laneSequence int = 0, 
    @rfidUniqueId nvarchar(50) = '',
    @planningLaneSeq nvarchar(10)= '',
    @sensorId nvarchar(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NULLIF(@laneSequence, '') IS NULL select @laneSequence = 0
    if NULLIF(@rfidUniqueId, '') is null select @rfidUniqueId = 'null-recd'
    if NULLIF(@planningLaneSeq, '') is null select @planningLaneSeq = 'null-recd'
    if NULLIF(@sensorId, '') is null select @sensorId = 'null-recd'
    --else
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_SS_LaneTimings]
           ([laneSequence]
           ,[timestamp]
           ,[rfidUniqueId]
           ,[planningLaneSeq]
           ,[sensorId]) output inserted.ID
     VALUES
           (@laneSequence
           ,getdate()
           ,@rfidUniqueId
           ,@planningLaneSeq
           ,@sensorId)
END
```

This is how I am sending it (Python3):

```
def setup_http_request(rfidUniqueId, mac_address, my_id_count):
    apiRequest = url + "?laneSequence=" + str(my_id_count) + "&rfidUniqueId=" + rfidUniqueId + "&planningLaneSeq=" + str(my_id_count) + "&sensorId=" + str(mac_address)
    send_http_request(apiRequest)

def send_http_request(apiRequest):
    try:
        auth = HttpNtlmAuth(db_user,db_password)
        response = requests.post(apiRequest,auth=auth)
```

I am getting a response status_code of 200, but I am not seeing the value that is meant to be returned, and the records added are showing all fields were received as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually solved this by first opening a session with the sql server:

```
session=requests()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(db_user,db_password)
r=session.get(baseUrl)
```

Then I changed my .post to a .get.

```
response = session.get(apiRequest)
```

Now I am getting my value back of the new records ID AND the data correctly written to my SQL Table.